# Why cant my anchor fire this javascript object?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page with a linked javascript object:

```
//the constructor function
function NewsScroller() {

}


//now put some config objects using the JSON structure
NewsScroller.prototype.config = {
    serviceUrl : '/NewsProvider.svc/rest/GetNews/',
    pageIndex : 0
}


//the argumented constuctor for this object
NewsScroller.prototype.init = function () {


    this.getNews(this.config.pageIndex);
    console.log(this.config.pageIndex);

}

NewsScroller.prototype.decreasePage = function () {

    console.log('current page index ' + this.config.pageIndex);

}
```

Then I have the page ready declaration:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var newsScrollerForPage = new NewsScroller();
            newsScrollerForPage.init();

            newsScrollerForPage.decreasePage();

        });

    </script>
```

Which produces the result:

> current page index 0

I want to call the function from an anchor tag so I have:

```
<div class="scroller-left">
    <a id="scroller-left-a" href="javascript:newsScrollerForPage.decreasePage();">
        <img src="/Images/Left-Scroller.jpg"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

But when I click the anchor I get:

> newsScrollerForPage is not defined

Why is this? Surely I should be able to call the object and function just like I did in the .ready method?

Answer (score 1):

You define the newsScrollerForPage inside the ready function with local scope (by using "var"), you can't use it outside of there except if you define a function in the same scope which uses it (scope is evaluated from where functions are defined, not from where they are called).

You can quickly fix the issue by taking away the var from before it (making it more global rather than local in scope) but I wouldn't suggest this as the best solution.

Better would be to link up the anchor like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var newsScrollerForPage = new NewsScroller();
        newsScrollerForPage.init();

        newsScrollerForPage.decreasePage();

        document.getElementById("scroller-left-a").onclick=function()
        {
             newsScrollerForPage.decreasePage();
             return false;
        }

    });
```

and removing the href from the HTML element.

Comment: I thought that because of closure then the page would gave access to the variables inside that function even after it is returned?

Comment: But yeah your right just about the clousre thing how does that work? Is it only a function that has access?

Comment: By changing the A from a link to an anchor, it might as well be removed completely and the click listener put on the image. Alternatively, the A should have an href value that does more or less what the listener does with navigation cancelled if the listener executes successfully.